# Is it possible to overwrite native Es6 promise resolve method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

> I know that it's not the best approach to overwrite native JS API and I do it more for experiment.

I would like to overwrite **Promise** resolve method handler to do some extra logic on each resolve. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? I mean if you're able to overwrite the entire Promise object then it's possible. If you're not able to then I'd imagine you're only able to change the prototype promise objects and not the base Promise object itself

Comment: Since you are using es6, I would rather go ahead and create a wrapper class

Comment: could you show an example? and please keep in mind that I would like to keep Promise class name.

Comment: You want to rewrite Promise.resolve ?  If so, that really IS a bad idea. If you want to create a promise and control how resolve is called, that is not only a good idea, it's normal.  new Promise((resolve,reject) => { /*now its up to you how/if to call resolve or reject in here*/ })

Comment: I want to add extra actions AFTER EACH resolve

Comment: @STEVER: It doesn't sound like you want to overwrite `Promise.resolve`, but rather that you want to decorate the `resolve` callback. Regardless, neither is a good idea. What do you need this for?

Comment: to have AngularJS ES6 promise support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to wrap `Promise.prototype.then` method.

```
Promise.prototype.then = (oldThen=>{
    return function then(_successHandler, _rejectHandler){
        /* your logic here; 
        remember: both successHandler and rejectHandler can be non-functions */
        return oldThen.call(this, wrappedSuccessHandler, wrappedRejectHandler);
    }
})(Promise.prototype.then);
```

This code won't be able to intercept `new Promise()` calls, but there is other workaround for this:

```
class SubPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(function(_resolve, _reject) {
           /* your code goes here */
           return executor(wrappedResolve, wrappedReject);
        });
    }

    then(success, reject) {
        return super.then(wrappedSuccessHandler, wrappedRejectHandler);
    }
}
window.Promise = SubPromise;
```

It replaces global `Promise` property with your implementation, so all subsequent calls resolving to `window.Promise` will return your implementation.

See [25.4.5.3 Promise.prototype.then](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.then) in spec for further details (with default handlers "thrower" and "identity").

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I think the "your code goes here" part leaves a lot out. How do you imagine wrapping `wrappedResolve`, `wrappedReject`, `wrappedSuccessHandler`, and `wrappedRejectHandler`?

Comment: This does not appear to overwrite the implementation of promises that come from specifying "async" before a function.